# Serial Port Write Echo

Tags: android, serial-port

I know posts are there related to this point but it did not help me.I have a Wandboard running Android and it is connected to PC via USB port.I am using SerialPort .Net class to read and write data.It is designed as Request response manner.PC will request for data once in 5 seconds so it will write to port and wait for Wandboard to respond back within 1 second.If it responds then through SerialPort read method it will read data and so on the process will go on.The problem I am facing is the data that I wrote to the port is echoed back along with the desired response from the wandboard.the data that I wrote to the port is first in the order.No matter what I do it always echoes back my written data.To come up with a temporary solution,I am writing the data and appending new line at the end,so when I read post that as I am getting echo I skip the data till the first newline I get .

I know this is not a good approach but I have tried enough and could not stop port from echoing back what I had written.any help is highly appreciated.

Here is the code for writing and reading .

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes and receives data from AP board
    /// </summary>
    private void RequestAndResponse()
    {

        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                if (myserialPort2 != null)
                {
                    int iwriteSize = 5;

                    if ( !myserialPort2.IsOpen)
                    {
                        myserialPort2.Open();
                    }

                    byte[] bytearrayOfSendCommand = new byte[iwriteSize];

                    bytearrayOfSendCommand[0] = 0x48;
                    bytearrayOfSendCommand[1] = 0x41;
                    bytearrayOfSendCommand[2] = 0x41;
                    bytearrayOfSendCommand[3] = 0x42;
                    bytearrayOfSendCommand[4] = 0x0A;

                    myserialPort2.Write(bytearrayOfSendCommand, 0, iwriteSize);

                    int size = myserialPort2.BytesToRead;
                    char[] bContent = new char[size];

                    var buffsize = myserialPort2.ReadBufferSize;
                    myserialPort2.Read(bContent, 0, size);

                    lock (objLocker)
                    {
                        char[] bContentTemp = bContent;

                       // ConsumePacketData(bContentTemp);
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000);

                }

            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
               //to be implemented later
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I have a Wandboard ... connected to PC via USB port"*  -- That's an ambiguous statement.  The *"USB port"* on which device?  Are you using a USB-to-USB connection?   Most likely you are using the RS-232 port on the Wandboard and a USB-to-RS232 adapter on the PC side.

Comment: Show us code. What you want to do in English may differ in implementation.

Comment: I have added the code above.Have a look also details about Wandboard are provided in discussion with Igor Gorjanc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your USB to Serial driver settings for the Echo option.

Comment: Can you tell where to check that?

Comment: @user4439379 Depends on device/drivers you have. But first of all, try this: unplug serial your Android device from a serial port (and leave serial port connected to a PC). Do you still get an echo? If yes, you need to check on your PC or USB to Serial interface, otherwise the problem is on the Android-device side.

Comment: If I unplug the the Android Device in between and keep the usb cable attached to the PC which is running windows 7 the SerialPort becomes null so then how can I check for echo ?

Comment: So you plug USB directly into Android device? What Android device do you have? Please give us some more info about your hardware...

Comment: I have a board named Wandboard which runs Android 4.3 .You can google about Wandboard .It has usb mini port which I connect to Windows using USB 2.0 slot.Then in Device manager,under Ports(COM & LPT) it appears as a COM7 ,which I use to instantiate SerialPort class. We are using driver from 
http://www.lpcware.com/content/project/nxpusblib
where in we have just modified the HardwareIds that came with Wandboard .This driver makes it available under Ports(COM & LPT) section.

Comment: This is an open source library. Can you please check, if this library provides echo? Or is it maybe Android device?

Comment: Try to send `ATE0` to device. Does it change anything?

Comment: I am sending ATE0 to wandboard and I am reading back the same ATE0.
App at wandboard side understands a request when it reads new line as the last byte from the request but apart from receiving the same data that I just wrote I am getting carriage return "\r" before newline character that I had added at the last.